# Add previous value in foreach - PHP

Tags: php

Let's say I have data string like this...

```
one=1&two=2&three=3&four=4&two=2
```

I'm using php `foreach` to grab the key/value and sort how I need it at this point

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
   if ($key == "two") {
    // $result = Take $value and add it to the previous $value .",";
   }
}
```

The goal I am trying to reach is how do I take the duplicate keys and add the previous value generated in the loop. For example: The solution would be `$result = 2,2,`

Comment: If you `POST`ed that to your server, you'd only see one `two`, you would not see both values.

Comment: Hey to get access to the name structure of any array ie $_POST, or $myarray use print_r and <pre></pre>. <http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're `POST`ing the string in the question to your server, you would only see one value of `two`, not both.  The 2nd one would overwrite the first value.

If you want multiple values for a key, you can make it an array by using `[]`.

```
one=1&two[]=2&three=3&four=4&two[]=2
```

Now, `$_POST['two']` will be an array (`one`, `three` and `four` will be strings).

Answer (score 1):

This will not work. You get only the last value from POST, GET and REQUEST. You need to parse the $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], and if you parsed it, you can iterate your array:

```
foreach(explode('&',$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) as $k => $v)
{
 $val = explode('=',$v);
 $result[$val[0]] = isset($result[$val[0]]) ? $result[$val[0]].','.$val[1]:$val[1];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//initial data string
$string = "one=1&two=2&three=3&four=4&two=2";

$results = array();

$data = explode('&', $string);

foreach($data as $param) {

    $query = explode('=', $param);

    $key = $query[0];
    $value = $query[1];

    // check to see if the key has been seen before. 
    // if not, store it in an array for now.
    if(!isset($results[$key])){
        $results[$key] = array($value);
    }
    else{
        // the key is a duplicate, store it in the array
        $results[$key][] = $value;
    }

}

// implode the arrays so that they're in the $result = "2,2" format
foreach($data as $key => $value){
    $data[$key] = implode(',', $value);
}
```

Also its been mentioned, but if this is coming from a server post then you won't get duplicate keys.

Comment: Don't you also need to explode on `=`?

Comment: Yes, i there was no question mark in the question so I left it out of the answer, but if you had one in there you should take it out for this to work

Comment: No, I meant you need to do `list($key, $value) = explode('=', $value)`.  (I was trying to say you need to explode the equal sign.  The question mark was because I was asking a question :-P)

Answer (score 1):

Bearing in mind [Rocket's advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10710055/618347) about multiple POSTed values, you could use `implode()` on any arrays that arrive:

```
foreach($_POST as $key=>$value)
{
    if(is_array($value))
        $_POST[$key]=implode(',',$value);
}
```

to get the string value that you seem to be after.

Answer (score 0):

Store them as an array outside the foreach loop.

```
$keys = [];
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
   if ($key == "two") {
     $keys[] = $value;
   }
}
return $keys
```

Comment: You can't have two of the same keys in an array.  This code could just be simplified down to `$keys = $_POST['two']` (this would be a string, not an array).

Comment: fyi In php you don't need to initialize a array outside of a foreach, in order to have access to the array. Just add stuff to the array and return it when you're finished.